# Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in ******/cartOutputExtra.php on line 70 Unable to retrieve order details

Tags: php, mysqli

There have been lots of posts about this and crawled them all but can't figure out why im getting this message. I am not good with SQl and this coding so really hope someone can help.

A customer can checkout and order fine but after Sagepay always presented with the above error message. (line 70 in bold below)

```
$query="SELECT surname, town, county, country, currencyID, goodsTotal, shippingTotal, taxTotal, discountTotal FROM $tableOrdersHeaders WHERE orderID = '$myOrderID' AND randID = '$myRandID' LIMIT 1";

        **$result = mysqli_query($query) or die( "Unable to retrieve order details");**
        $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result); 

        if ($num_results > 0){
            // build the array from the results
            $ga_order = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
        } else {
            die( "No matching order found");
```

Now the DB access file for SQLI code I believe it uses is

```
function connect($sql_host_name,$sql_username,$sql_password,$sql_database_name) {
        $this->currentDatabase = $sql_database_name;
        $this->resID = @mysqli_connect($sql_host_name,$sql_username,$sql_password);
        if ($this->resID == FALSE) {
            $this->lastError = "Could not connect to mySQL server";
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            if (@mysqli_select_db($this->resID, $sql_database_name)) {
                return TRUE;
            } else {
                return @mysqli_query($this->resID,"create database $sql_database_name");
                return FALSE;
```

Really hope someone can help.

Comment: Check your query. That is where the error will be. If you can check the query using an actual MySQL terminal, it will give you more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the procedural style of mysqli functions, you `mysqli_query` needs the connection variable as the first argument, followed by the query string.

It looks like you are just giving it the query string on here: `$result = mysqli_query($query) or die( "Unable to retrieve order details");`.

You'll want something like: `$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)`.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Hello
I have tried adding $connection to the string before and received same error message? Tried $connect & $connection as suggested on other posts.

Comment: Without knowing the exact structure of your code provided, I'm not 100% sure what variable is your mysql link, but it _looks_ like it should be `$this->resID`.